# RViz segfaults upon receiving mesh marker

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, markers.rviz, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running RViz and a custom plugin inside of rqt and I am trying to publish an STL mesh marker from my custom plugin and have RViz display it. The following is the message that I send to RViz (captured using rostopic echo)

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: /base_link
ns: model_mesh
id: 0
type: 10
action: 0
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  orientation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
scale: 
  x: 1.0
  y: 1.0
  z: 1.0
color: 
  r: 0.0
  g: 1.0
  b: 0.0
  a: 1.0
lifetime: 
  secs: 0
  nsecs: 0
frame_locked: False
points: []
colors: []
text: ''
mesh_resource: file:///home/bid019/models/CAD/exerciseBall.STL
mesh_use_embedded_materials: False
```

Whenever this message is sent RViz crashes. The following stack trace was obtained from gdb.

```
#0  0x00007fff9c4b0834 in ogre_tools::STLLoader::load(unsigned char*) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#1  0x00007fff9c4937d8 in rviz::loadMeshFromResource(std::string const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#2  0x00007fff8e443134 in rviz::MeshResourceMarker::onNewMessage(boost::shared_ptr<visualization_msgs::Marker_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<visualization_msgs::Marker_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libdefault_plugin.so
#3  0x00007fff8e441a2f in rviz::MarkerBase::setMessage(boost::shared_ptr<visualization_msgs::Marker_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libdefault_plugin.so
#4  0x00007fff8e431e9b in rviz::MarkerDisplay::processAdd(boost::shared_ptr<visualization_msgs::Marker_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libdefault_plugin.so
#5  0x00007fff8e432513 in rviz::MarkerDisplay::processMessage(boost::shared_ptr<visualization_msgs::Marker_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libdefault_plugin.so
#6  0x00007fff8e4326bb in rviz::MarkerDisplay::update(float, float) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libdefault_plugin.so
#7  0x00007fff9c467ff2 in rviz::DisplayGroup::update(float, float) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#8  0x00007fff9c50857e in rviz::VisualizationManager::onUpdate() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#9  0x00007ffff276887a in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#10 0x00007ffff276ca31 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#11 0x00007ffff0bc7e2c in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#12 0x00007ffff0bce4a0 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#13 0x00007ffff1bf2186 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
#14 0x00007ffff27544dd in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#15 0x00007ffff2784323 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#16 0x00007ffff2781629 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#17 0x00007ffff4233e04 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff4234048 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff42340ec in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff27817a1 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#21 0x00007ffff0c69bb6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#22 0x00007ffff27530af in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#23 0x00007ffff27533a5 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#24 0x00007ffff2758b79 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#25 0x00007ffff1bae1f0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
#26 0x000000000052c6d5 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#27 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#28 0x000000000052ca8d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#29 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#30 0x000000000052ca8d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#31 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#32 0x00000000005b7392 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#33 0x0000000000469663 in ?? ()
#34 0x00000000004699e3 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#35 0x0000000000469f1c in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#36 0x000000000046ab81 in Py_Main ()
#37 0x00007ffff7817ec5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x46ac3f <main>, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdb48, init=<optimised out>, fini=<optimised out>, rtld_fini=<optimised out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdb38) at libc-start.c:287
#38 0x000000000057497e in _start ()
```

I also tried to have RViz running by itself and my plugin running in rqt, but this error still occurs. Can anyone tell me what is causing this error?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with the latest packages from apt-get.
Here is the STL file that is causing me problems (other meshes cause issues as well) [STL file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yyuanzs08tqqt6/exerciseBall.STL?dl=0)
And here is the [RViz config file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbo96r2ma2axda1/feature_fitting.rviz?dl=0) that I am using. This also has a MarkerArray and a PointCloud2 display set up, but at the moment no messages are being published to those displays.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202801/rviz-segfaults-upon-receiving-mesh-marker/) by [Bidski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20952/bidski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I figured out the cause of the segfault.

RViz only supports binary STL files and I was using ASCII STL files.

Perhaps RViz should be updated so that it detects and then cleanly rejects (or even better, to actually handle) ASCII STL files rather than segfaulting?

---

Originally posted by [Bidski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20952/bidski/) with karma: 96 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-12**:
Perhaps submit this as a feature request to the [rviz issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues)?